# Python requests function: url formatting unexpected ascii output

Tags: python, python-requests

I am getting unexpected ASCII characters while using the `requests` library in Python 3.

```
search_terms = ["ö", "é", "ä"]
url = "http://www.domain.com/search"

for i in search_terms:
    r = requests.get(url, i)
```

Which returns:

```
http://www.domain.com/search?%C3%B6
http://www.domain.com/search?%C3%A9
http://www.domain.com/search?%C3%A4
```

Although I expected:

```
http://www.domain.com/search?%F6
http://www.domain.com/search?%E9
http://www.domain.com/search?%E4
```

Can someone explain what happened and hint at me how to get the desired results?

Comment: Do you use Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Python 3. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out without any further import statements. I am using the `encode` method now.

Old code:

```
for i in search_terms:
    r = requests.get(url, i)
```

New code:

```
for i in search_terms:
    r = requests.get(url, i.encode("iso-8859-1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that requests first encode the unicode strings as utf-8 and then quote them.

```
>>> urllib.quote(u'ö'.encode('utf-8')) 
%C3%B6
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's UTF-8 encoded.

```
>>> u'ö'.encode()
b'\xc3\xb6'
>>> u'é'.encode()
b'\xc3\xa9'
>>> u'ä'.encode()
b'\xc3\xa4'
```

What it seems you want is latin encoding.
You can achieve it like this:

```
# Python 3
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> quote('ö', encoding='iso-8859-1')
'%F6'
```

Comment: Ok. I see and managed to implement the `quote` function into my code, thx. But it kinda fells like an avoidable workaround. Do you know if it is possible to address the coding directly with `requests`?